# Problem : lapply(na.omit) delete all values

Tags: r, dataset, lapply, na, erase

I am analysing data and to use the screenIsotopeData() function, the guide indicated to use lapply(dta, na.omit) to get read of the missing value.
When I apply it, the only result is that it delete all the data ... Do you have any idea on what can I do, I do not understand because in so few character I have difficulty to see where is my mistake ... ? I do not understand because this morning the same code line was functioning well ?

```
mare_A <- read.csv2('Donnees_iso_Angers_79171_009_Zoe.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ";") # To simplify, pond number 79171-009 would be named
mare_A
mare_A <- lapply(mare_A, na.omit)
screenIsotopeData(mare_A)
```

Here is what my data looks like (~) and I want to keep the more dCc and and dNc even if I only have few dCb1 for example

| dCc | dNc | dCb1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29.56 | 10,3 | 6,69 |
| -29.46 | 10 | 4,87 |
| -24.92 | NA | NA |

Comment: Share a reproducible example of your dataset. Also put the name of the package you are using, like : I am using `tRophicPosition` package of R.

Comment: you should only need to do `na.omit(mare_A)`, this will remove rows of a data frame with any NAs